# Can't publish R Markdown file to RPubs

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to rectify this error code?. I got this while i was trying to publish an R Markdown file onto Rpubs:

```
 Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
 cannot open the connection
 Calls: <Anonymous> -> write.dcf -> file
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In dir.create(accountDir, recursive = TRUE) :
 cannot create dir 'D:\', reason 'Permission denied'
 2: In file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
 cannot open file 'D://rsconnect/documents/html.Rmd/rpubs.com/rpub/Document.dcf': No such file or directory
 Execution halted
```

How do i fix this error?. I already have an RPubs account but have never published before.

[Screenshot of Error Code in R Markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlnyl.jpg)